# Include NuGet Utility Package when building csproj

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild, nuget

I need to use a NuGet package containing a utility for my project. It contains several binaries (EXEs and DLLs).

I've added it to my project successfully but I suspect the nupkg isn't formed correctly because I cannot use any of its DLLs or EXEs in my project without manually pointing to the package in my local NuGet cache. When compiling, none of its resources are added to the output (I assume this is because nothing is referenced in my code).

I'd like to create a wrapper project to call the binaries but I'd also like other project devs to be able to compile the solution without adjusting directory variables. Ideally, I could configure the csproj to pull in the bits directly from the local package cache. I think this would be possible by setting the `Generate Path Property` value to `Yes` in Visual Studio, but the variable cannot be found when I attempt to use an `<Include/>` statement in the csproj file.

Is what I'm asking possible? Namely, reference the NuGet package bits within my csproj to ensure the binaries are dropped in the compilation output? Can I do this with the Path Property, or is there something else I can do without directly committing the package's binaries into my project?

(I realize I need to work with the developer to fix whatever issue they have with their package, but I have no direct influence at the moment so this is the best I can do at the moment).

Comment: The generate path property should work as described here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-references-in-project-files#generatepathproperty - if not then we probably need more detail on what is going on. This GeneratePathProperty causes NuGet to define an MSBuild property in the .nuget.g.props file inside the obj directory. These properties are available in your main project to use as needed.

Comment: I believe I solved the issue. I may have been using the variable in the wrong directive - a misunderstanding of the 'Link' attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this out, mostly due to misunderstanding how some of the different tags and attributes are meant to be used.

To achieve the desired effect, I did the following:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="$(Pkg{PackageId})\**">
      <Link>{NameOfSolutionDirectory}\%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)</Link>
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>
```

Where `{PackageId}` is the name of the NuGet package (this step requires setting 'Generate Path Property' to 'Yes' in the package properties via Solution Explorer), and `{NameOfSolutionDirectory}` is the name of a folder within the solution I'd like to use for containing those bits, if you're as concerned about keeping the project as organized as I am. The `{}` should be excluded when replacing these values.

If you want to scope to a specific directory within the package contents, do it within the `Include` attribute. The `**` is necessary if you want to include **all** files within that directory, or else you can scope by extension or whatever additional pattern you'd like.